# What are examples of scalable classical LDPC codes?

Tags: error-correction

Where can I find examples of "scalable" good LDPC codes, namely classical codes with properties [n, O(n), O(n] and an explicit prescription of how to increase the bit number n?

I am new to this field, so I do not know whether this is an obvious question or something that does not exist at all.

Answer (score 2):

## Good Classical LDPC Code of Infinitely Large Lengths.

So, the state-of-the-art solution is attributed to [Sipser and Shpilman](https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/PAPERS/expandersIT.pdf), and the modern formulation of the idea is remarkably simple. Let $C_0$ be $\Delta$-length linear binary code for some **finite** $\Delta$. Now let $\{ G_{n} \}$ be a family of $\Delta$-regular graphs, such that $G_{n}$ has $n$ edges.

Now Define the Code $C_{n}$ to be all the assignments of $n$ bits over the $G_{n}$ edges such that any vertex in the graph sees on its local view (edges adjoint to it) a codeword of $C_{0}$. Consider the following:

1. That construction invented by [Tanner](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1056404), by definition, any check $C_{n}$ has weight at most the degree of the graph, namely $\Delta$. By simple linear algebra, one can show that if the rate of $C_{0}$ is greater than half, then $C_{n}$ has a positive rate.
2. Sipser and Shpilman proved that if the graph is an [expander graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph), then the code $C_{n}$ also has a linear distance. In particular, they present a simple proof that any sublinear assignment of bits (non-zero bits) on the edges implies that there is at least one vertex that sees a non-trivial local view (means at least one $1$-bit) yet that local view has not enough bits to exceeds the distance of $C_{0}$ and therefore can't be a codeword of it.
3. We know how to construct explicitly family of expanders graph, For example, consider [Lubotzky](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/%7Ealexlub/PAPERS/ramanujan%20graphs/ramanujanGraphs.pdf), in which the graph is a Cayley graph.

So now it should be clear how to construct a family of good **classical** LDPC codes.

## BTW - QLDPC.

The construction of [good quantum LDPC code](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.13641) family is not so different from the above, and even those that prove that the construction obtains a linear distance is **hard** the technical implementation is easy.

Comment: Thanks. If I require only a constant rate and $d \geq \sqrt{n}$, are there other examples?